# not able to access mywebsite in webbrowser

Tags: iis, asp-classic, dns, hosting

my website opens with xx.xxx.xxx.xxx IP address till friday it was working fine..after wards not able view the site in webbrowser...what could be the problem ? how can we solve it?

My server with this IP is working and can able to view the updated data in database ..but not able to view, or open the page of website.before the website under IIS configuration was stooped and now started again..still no use..am couldnt view Login page at all.My application was developed in classic asp long back.Kindly give me any suggestion to this...its very urgent...

I tried browsing the website in IIS manger(server) .It showing page cannot be displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to me more clear. Is it classic ASP or ASP.net? What has changed during the weekend? How can you view updated data in the database if the website doesn't work? Have you tried pinging the website? What is the error-message you get? Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: sorry it was typo error."classic asp ".I didnt change any thing.because am able to open the server where i could see updated data in database through receiver application. where as for web application viewing the data is different.i get data received message when i ping the IP in cmd prompt.Tired in different browsers too still could not view the login page(main page)

Comment: Okay. So the server can be reached and is responding. You will need access to the server to troubleshoot, which I hope you have. You could try in the command prompt -on the server- to restart IIS by typing 'iisreset'. The server will restart IIS, which sometimes solves IIS crashing or hanging. It sounds as if ASP is configured not to send detailed error messages, you could also try checking the application events in the event viewer on the server.

Comment: how could i figure out the error log in the application event in server event viewer!? and how can i solve it? am not aware of it

Comment: It depends; you need access to the server. Where is the server located, in your home/office or with a Service Provider? Can you access this server remotely using (for example) VNC or Remote Desktop? How dou you normally change settings in IIS on your server?

Comment: i can access server remotely using Remote Desktop..

Comment: Perfect, then start a command (DOS) prompt and type 'iisreset'. This will restart IIS and possibly solve the problem. You can also right-click on the computer icon and select "manage". You can then check the event viewer to see if there are errors there that can clarify the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Don't Panic. Staying calm can avoid further damage.

While it's hard to tell what could be the problem, the first thing you can do is to "ping" the domain from terminal.Can you login remotely? "wget" (on linux) will download the files from website, and could help you see if the files on the site are still accessible.  Check from different browsers or machines, if possible. I'm no expert in asp or IIS, so won't advice on that front. But once I had faced the same situation with my website. So I just called up the hosting service provider, and it turned out it was their problem, and they brought the server online. If it's okay from their end, you might have changed some configurations in your server or application or there might be some up-gradation changing parameters, or even an accidental deletion/ moving/ renaming of files.  Just try to remember what are the things you did with your server and application, before it went down, and also ask your server administrator. That will surely help you understand the problem better, if not help to solve it right away.

Good Luck.

Comment: Configuration settings was changed.Now it rectified and works fine.